# Run custom script before MSI installation/uninstallation in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I'm writing an MSI installer using Visual Studio 2010 and I was wondering if such is possible?

1. Run a custom script -- I basically need to run an exe process and wait for it to finish running -- BEFORE files are copied into the destination folder during installation.
2. Run a custom script -- again I need to run an exe process and wait for it to finish running -- BEFORE target files are uninstalled.

PS. I'm using C# for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a custom action executed before the files are installed/uninstall you need to schedule it in the beginning of the InstallExecuteSequence, under "LanchConditions" standard action for example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372038(v=vs.85).aspx

However, from what I know in VS you cannot show this standard action, so I don't see a way to add the custom action after it.

The "Install" step from VS is corespondent to "InstallFiles" standard action from what I know.

Comment: You could try Advanced Installer, or if you are looking for a free tool, Wix.
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html